# Slower than expected MongoDB performance on indexed larger-than-RAM datasets

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm dealing with an issue with a set of very large mongo collections (100GB+). These are made up of around 10M documents each, with the schema

- timestamp (integer)
- topic (string)
- message (bytes - this corresponds to a serialized value)

And we have indexes on timestamp, topic and timestamp + topic.

Each message set represents different "runs" of our underlying software.

Most timestamp/topic combinations are very small messages, however a few topics have very large messages. Our database has two types of collections

- One set only includes small messages (e.g. `SMALL_TOPIC`), total size 5GB or so
- One set includes small and large messages (e.g. `BIG_TOPIC`), total size 100GB or so - these are a superset of our small messages.

When we make a simple query, such as

```
db.find({'timestamp': {'$gt': 0 }, 'topic': 'SMALL_TOPIC'})
```

performs much more poorly on the 100GB set versus the 5GB set - **even on a cold run!**  For magnitudes, this query takes 30s on the 5GB dataset (vs. 10s or so when hot) and 15 minutes (!) on the 100GB dataset.

This seems quite surprising to me - it is a simple query and the index is being used. I naively assumed that the index would map to physical disk locations that would then mean that all that needs to be loaded from disk to RAM are the small topics - and adding extra documents that are large, but unrelated to the query, should not decrease performance.

I have been running some tests with copies of the collection stored in Postgres, and it turns out using Postgres alleviates the effect almost entirely (30s cold in the 5GB vs. 40s or so on the 100GB) - but a lot of our legacy infrastructure is in Mongo so it's not an easy switch.

I'm wondering if there's anyone out there who is more of an expert on WiredTiger and might know what could be causing this under the hood?

My best guess (which I've been unable to verify) is that WiredTiger is doing some paging of the underlying data store. Because the data is inserted sequentially (by timestamp) the pages that contain SMALL_TOPIC also contain BIG_TOPIC, thus under the hood WiredTiger is still having to manually read 100GB of the data. But this is just a guess - I haven't been able to figure out the details.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this or any way we could alleviate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some algorithms used for some internal operations have to aligns lenght of variable data on the max length of the longest data.

The cardinality associated with the target length, gives the surface of the data which, if it exceeds a certain threshold, can cause a different algorithmic behavior, for example using the disk rather than the memory...

Comment: This behaviour is what I was imagining - are there any docs on this?

Comment: Take a look on Microsoft Research publicated papers.... Like : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/GrpSets.pdf